# Animating a rotating tetrahedron about its rotational symmetry axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pst-solides3d

```
\documentclass[pstricks, border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{xfp}

\psset
{
    lightsrc=viewpoint,
    Decran=30,
    solidmemory,
}

\newcommand{\al}{3}
\newcommand{\ax}{4}
\edef\ax{\fpeval{\al+0.1}}

\newcommand{\ul}{0}
\newcommand{\um}{0.81731}
\newcommand{\un}{0.57620}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+{5}}{73}
{
    \begin{pspicture}[viewpoint=30 20 30 rtp2xyz] (-4.5,-3) (4.5,5)
        \defFunction[algebraic]{ntr}(x,y,z)
        {x*(\ul*\ul*(1-cos({\i})) + cos({\i})) + y*(\um*\ul*(1-cos({\i})) - \un*sin({\i})) + z*(\un*\ul*(1-cos({\i})) + \um*sin({\i}))}
        {x*(\ul*\um*(1-cos({\i})) + \un*sin({\i})) + y*(\um*\um*(1-cos({\i})) + cos({\i})) + z*(\un*\um*(1-cos({\i})) - \ul*sin({\i}))}
        {x*(\ul*\un*(1-cos({\i})) - \um*sin({\i})) + y*(\um*\un*(1-cos({\i})) + \ul*sin({\i})) + z*(\un*\un*(1-cos({\i})) + cos({\i}))}
        \psSolid[
            object=tetrahedron,
            action=draw*,
            r=2.12132,
            fillcolor=magenta!20,
            transform=ntr,
        ] %(0,0,0.71)
        \psSolid[
            object=line,
            args=-1 0 \fpeval{0-0.71} 1 0 \fpeval{1.41-0.71},
        ]
        \axesIIID[labelsep=10pt] (\al,\al,\al) (\ax,\ax,\ax)
    \end{pspicture}
}
\end{document}
```

I want to rotate the given tetrahedron about the given line. Doing this with solely `pst-solides3d` seems not possible - I at least didn't find any similar operations in the documentation. I suppose this will require Ti*k*Z.

My ultimate goal here is to produce an animation of the rotating tetrahedron, so there is a `multido` block in the code.

**Edit.** I think that can be done with `pst-solides3d`. Indeed, it has a pretty generic transformation option. The option accepts algebraic expressions. To use it, I first translated the present objects so that the line passes through the origin. I will then use the [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Rotation_2). The `\ul,\um,\un` is the coordinates of the unit vector parallel to the line. The only thing remains in this solution is to write the algebraic expression properly. My first try is in the edited code, though it fails with the following message:

```
DEBUG: FC_WEIGHT didn't match
Error: /undefined in
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   les_sommets   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   0.0   0.0   1.0
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1990   1   3   %oparray_pop   1989   1   3   %oparray_pop   1977   1   3   %oparray_pop   1833   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   3   --nostringval--   %repeat_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:739/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:120/200(L)--   --dict:750/1012(L)--   --dict:179/300(L)--   --dict:38/200(L)--   --dict:218/300(L)--   --dict:750/1012(L)--   --dict:2/3(L)--   --dict:3/3(L)--   --dict:3/3(L)--   --dict:3/3(L)--   --dict:14/22(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
Current file position is 429054
GPL Ghostscript 9.52: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Comment: Welcome! When you use `[viewpoint=20 {\i} 10 rtp2xyz]`, say, then clearly the thing gets rotated. It does not get rotated about the axis, for which you need to look up the precise definition of `viewport`, but it should be possible in principle. So the requirement of having this thing rotate does not imply that one needs to switch to Ti*k*Z. In fact, in Ti*k*Z you'r need to make sure that the 3d ordering is correct, which is automatic here (yet there are of course reasons that suggest to switch to Ti*k*Z).

Comment: Yeah, making `\i` y parameter of the viewpoint makes tetrahedron rotate. It actually was in the code, I removed it to prevent confusion :)

Comment: I've just read that it's not the parameter `y` but `theta` of `r theta phi rtp2xyz` as the definition of its documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get rid of the postscript error. This was achieved by removing the braces around the `\i`s and removing some invisible tab character (could be that my editor introduced them but I had to remove them). Together with the additional information in your own comments ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544767/animating-a-rotating-tetrahedron-about-its-rotational-symmetry-axis/545141?noredirect=1#comment1376993_545141) and [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544767/animating-a-rotating-tetrahedron-about-its-rotational-symmetry-axis/545141?noredirect=1#comment1377004_545141)) this yields

```
\documentclass[pstricks, border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{xfp}

\psset
{
    lightsrc=viewpoint,
    Decran=30,
    solidmemory,
}

\newcommand{\al}{3}
\newcommand{\ax}{4}
\edef\ax{\fpeval{\al+0.1}}

\newcommand{\ul}{0}
\newcommand{\um}{0.81731}
\newcommand{\un}{0.57620}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+{5}}{71}
{
    \begin{pspicture}[viewpoint=30 20 30 rtp2xyz] (-4.5,-3) (4.5,5)
        \defFunction[algebraic]{ntr}(x,y,z)
        {x*(\um*\um*(1-cos(\i*3.14159/180))+cos(\i*3.14159/180))+y*(\ul*\um*(1-cos(\i*3.14159/180))-\un*sin(\i*3.14159/180))+z*(\un*\um*(1-cos(\i*3.14159/180))+\ul*sin(\i*3.14159/180))}%
        {x*(\um*\ul*(1-cos(\i*3.14159/180))+\un*sin(\i*3.14159/180))+y*(\ul*\ul*(1-cos(\i*3.14159/180))+cos(\i*3.14159/180))+z*(\un*\ul*(1-cos(\i*3.14159/180))-\um*sin(\i*3.14159/180))}%
        {x*(\um*\un*(1-cos(\i*3.14159/180))-\ul*sin(\i*3.14159/180))+y*(\ul*\un*(1-cos(\i*3.14159/180))+\um*sin(\i*3.14159/180))+z*(\un*\un*(1-cos(\i*3.14159/180))+cos(\i*3.14159/180))}%
        \psSolid[
            object=tetrahedron,
            action=draw*,
            r=2.12132,
            fillcolor=magenta!20,
            transform=ntr,
        ] %(0,0,0.71)
        \psSolid[
            object=line,
            args=-1 0 \fpeval{0-0.71} 1 0 \fpeval{1.41-0.71},
        ]
        \axesIIID[labelsep=10pt] (\al,\al,\al) (\ax,\ax,\ax)
    \end{pspicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe trigonometric functions take their arguments in radians. We give it in degrees here.

Comment: @sevdaicmis I think you are right.

Comment: Okay, one last thing: the values of the `\ul` and `\um` should be interchanged. Then the tetrahedron will rotate about the drawn line.

Comment: @sevdaicmis Yes, now it looks right, I think.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm trying to achieve.